# Javascript: Update price on quantity (no multiplication)

Tags: javascript

Ok, I've got a unique one here and I've been searching all over the googles and stackoverflow and found nothing that matches exactly what I need.  Here's what I've got.

I have three checkboxes in a form, these represent 3 different "events".  What I need is that if a person checks any ONE checkbox the total is $30. If they check any two of the boxes the total is $40 and if they check all 3 the total is $50.  Since they may check any one, two, or all 3 boxes I can't have the prices set statically in the value.  I need something that say roughly "if 1 box selected, price is $30, if 2 boxes selected, price is $40, if 3 boxes selected, price is $50".

I'm good with PHP and mySQL and I know I could accomplish this with PHP but I would have to submit the form first before the price would update, this is why I need javascript to update the pricing as the user checks/unchecks boxes.  Thanks for all responses!

Comment: I hope you're not planning to use the price submitted by the form as the actual price of anything, otherwise I am going to get some free stuff from your site.

Comment: Not really, this just informs them of the price, later on they are directed to paypal and that price will be the PHP/MySQL as I had mentioned and that price is based on how many events they have signed up for in the database.  And even if they managed to hack that they still have to present their receipt before participating in any events AND they have to be registered users to pay first.  So no matter what we'll know who paid what. Thanks for your concern though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that should get you started - this is all based on the assumption that there are only 3 checkboxes on your whole page and that you're interested in all of them - you'll want to make a method like this respond to your checkbox elements' onclick events - I've found that to be more reliable than onchange.

```
        function updateTotal() {
            var checked = 0;
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (/checkbox/i.test(inputs[i].type) && inputs[i].checked) {
                    checked++;
                }
            }

            var priceInDollars = 0;
            switch (checked) {
                case 1:
                    priceInDollars = 30;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    priceInDollars = 40;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    priceInDollars = 50;
                    break;
            }

            var priceElement = document.getElementById("the id of your element where you'll print the price");
            priceElement.innerText = "$".concat(priceInDollars.toString());
        }
```

EDIT:

I'm not a JQuery master yet - I like the JQuery answer for retrieving the count much better than mine - much cleaner...

Comment: Brian, thanks for the quick response.  I do only have the three checkboxes, however, I also have 2 groups of radios.  Will this line take those into account or is it only worried about checkboxes?

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

Comment: Yep - not a problem at all - the line of code:  /checkbox/i.test(inputs[i].type) is a case insensitive regular expression check for the type of the input being checkbox...

Comment: Ok cool, perhaps I am doing something wrong then (likely), do I need to change anything besides the "the id of your element where you'll print the price".  I have changed that to             var priceElement = document.getElementById("totalTD"); and then I have a <td id='totalTD'> but its not getting updating on clicking.  I have the javascript entered at the beginning of the file in script tags.

Comment: Try alerting your price first just to make sure all is working within your page - just before var priceElement =..., put alert(priceInDollars).  If you see a price, I'd throw a span inside of your TD, give it an ID ('totalSP') and reference that instead of the TD ...

Comment: Ah, of course - good idea.  I did that and no alert pops up.  I had the code wrapped in script tags in my php file and got nothing so I moved it into an included .js file, but it still does nothing. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid.

Comment: I did change it to a <span id='totalTD'></span> btw too.

Comment: Yep, I'm stupid.  I forgot to include the triggers ie; onChange='updateTotal()'

Comment: LOL that was my last recommendation - make sure your inputs all say onchange="foo();".  Everything working now?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
var cont=$('#yourContainerId'),nbSelected=$(':checkbox:checked',cont).length,result=0;
if(nbSelected==1) result=30;
else if(nbSelected==2) result=40;
else if(nbSelected==3) result=50;
return result;
```

Comment: Darm, thanks for the quick response.  I know almost nothing about jQuery.  Can you explain to me how I would use this?  I'm trying to logic my way through it but so far I don't understand it enough to implement it.  Does this go in a script tag like javascript? How do I get the value of "result" into the "Total" <td> ?

Comment: @Scott If you're not already using jQuery, Brian's solution might be more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: 1. load jquery in your page header before any other jquery scripts (use google cdn, it will save you bandwidth: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js) 2.put my code in a script tag in your page, in a $.ready(function(){var cont=$('#yourContainerId');$(':checkbox',cont).click(function(){........});}); See the jQuery doc: http://jquery.com/

Comment: @Chris Ok thanks, I'm going to focus on that one until I get it working or until I get my hand held on this one ;)  I'm no master by any means at javascript either but I can at least understand most of what he wrote. :)

Answer (score 0):

well... it's been answered by a couple people already, but I like my way... so I'll post it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Hm9xH/1/

pure javascript and DOM, so no need to fiddle with libraries.

Comment: Click on the textbox without checking any checkboxes. Also, check a single checkbox, then uncheck it. Paying $20 for nothing sounds like a raw deal to me.

Comment: I made several assumptions on the business logic in my example.  I assumed that the user is paying for something regardless of whether he has checked any boxes.  This is because the user could leave all three unchecked.  I assumed that the checkboxes where being used for additional features (hence the variable name "options").  That being the case and the checkboxes consistently adding $10 to the total, I assumed that the base price was $20.  Furthermore, if this were to go into production, these options would be isolated in that "options" div. Nothing's broken.  It works the way I designed it